# Add multiple UIButtons with color images programmatically to the UIViewController scene

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, swift2

I have UIViewController class in which I add multiple color buttons programmatically to the scene. I have 11 different colors, so 11 UIButtons which I add to the scene in viewDidLoad function. See below how I add gray and red color buttons. Then I use function crayonsPressed action to select colors by tag. I do this way because UIButton selection depends on the tag value. As you can see this dependence by UIButton tag value, adding buttons this way in not good approach. I was wondering what would be the best way to programmatically add these 11 color buttons to the scene so that I don't have to repeat below code in viewDidLoad 11 times. My plan is to subclass this UIViewController to 11 more scenes in which they all will have same functionality for all 11 buttons, which is drawing.

Edited to load all image buttons with an array. Still need resolution on how to handle UIButton tag, so that when color button is pressed that color is selected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let colors: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)] = [
    (0, 0, 0),
    (105.0 / 255.0, 105.0 / 255.0, 105.0 / 255.0),
    (1.0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 1.0),
    (51.0 / 255.0, 204.0 / 255.0, 1.0),
    (102.0 / 255.0, 204.0 / 255.0, 0),
    (102.0 / 255.0, 1.0, 0),
    (160.0 / 255.0, 82.0 / 255.0, 45.0 / 255.0),
    (1.0, 102.0 / 255.0, 0),
    (1.0, 1.0, 0),
    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    ]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let arrayImages : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Grey")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Red")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Black")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Blue")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Brown")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "DarkGreen")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "DarkOrange")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Grey")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "LightBlue")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "LightGreen")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Yellow")!]

    var buttonX : CGFloat = 374.5


    for images in arrayImages {

        let imageButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: 643, width: 25, height: 125))
        buttonX = buttonX + 25 
        imageButton.setImage(images, for: UIControlState.normal)
        imageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crayonsPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(imageButton)

    }

    func crayonsPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var index = sender.tag ?? 0
    if index < 0 || index >= colors.count {
        index = 0
    }

    (red, green, blue) = colors[index]

    if index == colors.count - 1 {
        opacity = 1.0
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the image names in an array. Then loop through the array creating a button for each. Now your button code is only done once - inside the loop.

Comment: Edited to load image buttons with an array as suggested. Any way on how to handle UIButton tag, so that tag is correctly assigned to the color button. Really appreciate anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly suggested by @rmaddy to put the colours in an array and then use those colours in a loop. You may use a variable to keep track of the position of your array.

```
var i = 0

for images in arrayImages {

    let imageButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: 643, width: 25, height: 125))
    buttonX = buttonX + 25
    imageButton.tag = i
    imageButton.setImage(images, for: UIControlState.normal)
    imageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.crayonsPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(imageButton)
    i += 1
}
```

Now each of your buttons will have a valid `tag` value.

Comment: Ok. So now can I handle crayonsPressed? Thanks.

Comment: Yes now you should be able to handle the `crayonsPressed` method. Try the above code in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much Adeel. I appreciate your support. This has helped me. Personal question! Where are you from?

Comment: Adeel, do you use 'whatsup' application?

Answer (score 0):

After having Adeel and Rmaddy helping out, here is the final solution that should help anyone who may need it. The UIButton tag is assigned correctly to the button pressed. Please note that this applies to the programmatically adding buttons to the scene not using storyboard to a ViewController.

```
    let arrayImages : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Black")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Grey")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Red")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Blue")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "LightBlue")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "DarkGreen")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "LightGreen")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Brown")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "DarkOrange")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Yellow")!,
                                   UIImage(named: "Eraser")!]

    var buttonX : CGFloat = 374.5
    var i = 0        
    for images in arrayImages {

       let imageButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: 643, width: 25, height: 125))
        buttonX = buttonX + 25 // space buttons 25px apart
        imageButton.setImage(images, for: UIControlState.normal)
        imageButton.tag = i            
        imageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crayonsPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(imageButton)
        i += 1
    }

    func crayonsPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {      
    var index = sender.tag ?? 0
    if index < 0 || index >= colors.count {
        index = 0
    }
    (red, green, blue) = colors[index]

    if index == colors.count - 1 {
        opacity = 1.0
    }        
    }
```